# Upvote in reputation report does not show +10

Tags: support, reputation

Please see this snapshot. Do you notice how the points in the second post doesn't sum up like the first? Also the "+10" is missing for the upvote for "9 mins ago"

The overall total also remain unaffected. It should have been +10.

Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: You hit the rep cap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a maximum amount of reputation you can earn in one day using ordinary means; it's called the "reputation cap" and it's set at 200 points. Any points you earn for upvoted questions and answers after that don't count. That's what happened here: the last +10 didn't happen because you have hit the cap. The purpose of the cap is to make you go outside and get some fresh air once in a while.

Points accrued by earning bounties and getting answers accepted can earn you rep in excess of the cap.

Comment: Oh I see. I was not aware of that. I was confused because I have seen people getting more than 300 points... Now I understand it. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @sid read the faq for reputation, see here: [faq#reputation] or click any of the FAQ links on the site.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Thanks for the link. Strange. I have gone through the FAQ thoroughly in the past. But seems like I need to go through it again! Growing old I guess? hmph! More carefully this time.

Comment: @SiddharthRout you can exceed 200 from various methods, the most common is that an accepted answer (+15) does not count toward the cap. Lots more details in the FAQ.